# Как решить проблему с зависающим процессом, порожденным скриптом python?

Tags: python, tkinter, subprocess, telethon

**Предисловие.** Заинтересовался видео одного известного ютубера (название: Создаем свой Telegram на Python) в ходе которого разрабатывается телеграмм-клиент, использующий API. **Ближе к сути.**
Есть программа с примитивным графическим дизайном, вызывающая выполнение другого скрипта:

```
import tkinter as tk
import subprocess
import sys
import time

def connect():
    process = subprocess.Popen([sys.executable, "first.py"])
    process.wait()
    time.sleep(0.1)

    process2 = subprocess.Popen([sys.executable, "second.py"])
    process2.wait()
    time.sleep(0.1)

    process3 = subprocess.Popen([sys.executable, "third.py"])
    process3.wait()
    time.sleep(0.1)

root = tk.Tk()
root.title("Telegram")
root.geometry("300x50")
tk.Button(root, text='Connect', command=connect).pack()
root.resizable(False, False)
root.mainloop()
```

Cо скриптами first.py и second.py проблем не возникает, они отрабатывают и программа продолжает выполняться дальше, но вот с third.py возникает следующая проблема: в этом скрипте вызывается окно tkinter, в котором происходит вывод отправленных и полученных сообщений, но после того, как закрываешь это окно, основной скрипт продолжает ожидать, как будто third.py еще не отработал, соответственно главное окно с кнопкой зависает.[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Приходится вручную остановить отладку через pycharm (использую его).Если закомментировать строчку, то проблема уходит.

````
```
# process3.wait()
```
````

Однако этот процесс, который судя по всему мешал продолжить выполнение в первом случае, остается в диспетчере.
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Если этот процесс не закрыть, то подключение с API телеграмма не разрывается, соответственно нельзя установить новую сессию.
Код third.py:

```
import asyncio
from telethon import events
from telethon import TelegramClient
import time
import sqlite3
from tkinter import *
import threading
import json
import os
from lorem_text import lorem
from datetime import datetime
import sys

db = sqlite3.connect('Account.db', timeout=30)
cur = db.cursor()

cur.execute(f"SELECT NAME FROM Account WHERE ID = '{1}'")
friend = str(cur.fetchone()[0])
time.sleep(0.1)

window = Tk()
window.resizable(False, False)
window.grab_set()
window.focus_set()
window.title(f'Securegram. Диалог с {friend}')

messages = Text(window, bg="#d7d8e0")

f = open('self_name.txt')
self_name = str(f.readlines()[0])
f.close()

input_user = StringVar()
input_field = Entry(window, text=input_user)

cur.execute(f"SELECT API_ID FROM Account WHERE ID = '{1}'")
api_id = str(cur.fetchone()[0])
time.sleep(0.1)

cur.execute(f"SELECT API_HASH FROM Account WHERE ID = '{1}'")
api_hash = str(cur.fetchone()[0])
time.sleep(0.1)

session = "anon31"

client = TelegramClient("anon31", api_id, api_hash).start()
client.start()
time.sleep(0.1)
cur.execute(f"SELECT ID_SOB FROM Account WHERE ID = '{1}'")
id_sob = str(cur.fetchone()[0])
zorro = int(id_sob)
time.sleep(0.1)


def Enter_pressed(event):
    input_get = input_field.get()
    print(input_get)

    print("Зашифровка")

    sms = lorem.sentence()

    with open("1.json") as f:
        data4 = f.read()
    d = json.loads(data4)
    d["cover"] = sms
    d["secret"] = input_get
    with open("1.json", 'w') as f:
        f.write(json.dumps(d))

    os.system("stegcloak hide --config 1.json")

    print("Отправка шифровки")

    cur.execute(f"SELECT NAME FROM Account WHERE ID = '{1}'")
    name = str(cur.fetchone()[0])

    async def main():
        with open("out.txt", "r") as f1:
            data5 = f1.read()
            xxx = str(data5)
        await client.send_message(name, xxx)

    client.loop.run_until_complete(main())

    messages.insert(INSERT, '%s\n' % f'{datetime.now().strftime("%d.%m.%y %H:%M")} {self_name}: {input_get}')

    input_user.set('')

    return "break"


frame = Frame(window)

frame.pack()
messages.pack()
input_field.pack(side=BOTTOM, fill=X)
input_field.bind("<Return>", Enter_pressed)


def run_bot_events():
    loop = asyncio.new_event_loop()
    asyncio.set_event_loop(loop)
    loop.run_until_complete(async_run_events(loop))


async def async_run_events(loop):
    eventing_client = await TelegramClient("anon32", api_id, api_hash, loop=loop).start()

    @eventing_client.on(events.newmessage.NewMessage(from_users=zorro))
    async def handler(event):
        hhh = event.message.message
        if hhh is not None:
            with open("2.json") as f:
                data3 = f.read()
            d = json.loads(data3)
            d["message"] = str(hhh)
            with open("2.json", 'w') as f:
                f.write(json.dumps(d))
            os.system("stegcloak reveal --config 2.json")

            with open("out2.txt", "r") as f1:
                data2 = f1.read()
            print(data2)

        messages.insert(INSERT, '%s\n' % f'{datetime.now().strftime("%d.%m.%y %H:%M")} {friend}: {data2}')

    # messages.insert(INSERT, '%s\n' % data2)

    await eventing_client.run_until_disconnected()


threading.Thread(target=run_bot_events).start()
window.mainloop()
```

**Вопрос.** Подскажите, как сделать так, чтобы по закрытию окна, которое было создано в third.py скрипт заканчивал свою работу и не блокировал дальнейшую работу программы? **p.s.** Ссылку на github со всеми упомянутыми здесь файлами, а также программой автора, прилагаю: https://github.com/zentkhv/example.

Comment: Вообще нужно смотреть, что там за скрипты, но думаю вместо subprocess можно их импортировать и вызывать через threading или multiprocessing.

Answer (score 0):

Вообще нужно смотреть, что там за скрипты, но думаю вместо subprocess можно их импортировать и вызывать через threading или multiprocessing. –
insolor

Поменял на threading, спасибо

Answer (score -1):

```
def CloseClick():
    os.sys.exit() #функция для полного завершения

btnClose = Button(window, text = "Close", command = CloseClick)
```

#Как её вызвать на Х - хз. Можно попробовать что-то вроде

```
if __name__ == "__main__":
    os.sys.exit()
```

Comment: добро пожаловать на Stack Overflow на русском! пожалуйста, постарайтесь оставлять чуть более развёрнутые ответы. дополнить ответ можно, нажав [edit]